# CryptKeeper's icon not showing in panel in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04

I installed "CryptKeeper" an hour ago, and I just cant get it's icon to be shown in the panel.

I've tried running this code in the Terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

but the output was "No such schema 'com.canonical.Unity.Panel' ".
After searching a little, I discovered that the Unity notification area (systray) whitelist is no longer available in Ubuntu 13.04. 
I also tried using "dconf-tools" ,but it didn't help.
I've been searching quite a lot, and the only option ,that I encountered, to get the icon to be shown in the panel is to get the Unity systray whitelist back in Ubuntu 13.04. I am not sure that's a good idea since it's obsolete.

Any ideas would be appreciated.